# how can i set email by a variable in cakehphp app_local

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

In app_local how can i set username and password with variables in cakephp 4 ? I want to get the values from a table.
Or if i cant use a variable to set the email then is there another way?

```
 'EmailTransport' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                'port' => 465,
                'username'=>'xx@gmail.com',
                'password'=>'xx',

//how can i do this code below with the variables as i cant get data from a table in this file?     
      
    'EmailTransport' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                'port' => 465,
                'username'=>$username,
                'password'=>$password,
```

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/email.html

Comment: You text says CakePHP 4, the link and the tag says CakePHP 3?

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/email.html#configuring-transports

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/configuration.html#storing-runtime-configuration

Comment: The link has been updated to cake4 but its the same code/problem anyway.  I cant see if anyone has added a solution to this though from 3 posts ? Unless I am missing something here.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the default email settings in your configuration file.

In your controller actions do something like this:

```
use Cake\Mailer\MailerAwareTrait;
use Cake\Mailer\TransportFactory;
// ....
public function index()
{
    $users = $this->Users->find();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        TransportFactory::drop('gmail'); // If you wish to modify an existing configuration, you should drop it, change configuration and then re-add it.
        TransportFactory::setConfig('gmail', [
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'username' => $user->mail_username,
            'password' => $user->mail_password,
            'className' => 'Smtp',
        ]);

        $this->getMailer('Users')->send('user', [$user]);
    }
}
```

**or try this:**

```
$this->getMailer('Users')
->drop('gmail')
->setConfig('gmail', [
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => $user->mail_username,
    'password' => $user->mail_password,
    'className' => 'Smtp',
 ])
->send('user', [$user]);
```

**read more** https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/email.html#configuring-transports

**note:** for security reasons, be sure not to save a plain text password to the database